# how to use protected static in php?

Tags: php

```
protected static $table = array(
            'createQuery' => 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xf_user_notes` (
            `note_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `given_user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
            `received_user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
            `note_message` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            `note_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`note_id`)
        ) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;',
            'dropQuery' => 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `xf_user_notes`'
    );
```

Above code is taken from one website.

Question:

I know:protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes.static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class. But usually in which situation we use protected static? and can anyone give me a live example? Thanks.

Comment: Static methods are usually nothing more than helper methods that have code you possibly don't want to be public.

Comment: See http://kunststube.net/static, around the last third.

Comment: Did you read any of the numerous pages you can find by googling "in which situation we use protected static" (your own wording)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting myself from [here](http://kunststube.net/static):

> Static class properties are useful for *static data*. That is, data
>   that a class instance depends on, but which never changes and is
>   possibly large. Totally hypothetical example:
>
> ```
> class Database {
>
>     protected static $types = array(
>         'int'    => array('internalType' => 'Integer', 'precision' => 0,      ...),
>         'string' => array('internalType' => 'String',  'encoding'  => 'utf-8', ...),
>         ...
>     )
>
> }
> ```
>
> Let's assume this database class needs to do something with different
>   types of data coming from a database and maps database types to
>   internal types. To do this it needs a type map. This map is always the
>   same for each instance of `Database` and is used by several methods of
>   `Database`. Well, why not make it a `static` property, which is never
>   modified but only ever read from? It saves a little bit of memory,
>   because the data is shared between all instances of `Database`. Since
>   the data is only ever accessed from inside the class itself, this
>   doesn't create any external dependencies. Static properties should
>   never be made publicly accessible, since then they're just global
>   variables. And we have seen where that goes...
>
> Static properties may also be useful to cache some data which is
>   identical across all instances of a class once it has been computed
>   and can easily be shared across instances as optimization. There are
>   some such instances where this is useful. Static properties mostly
>   present an optimization technique, they should not be viewed as a
>   programming philosophy.

Comment: it seems that u mainly talk about static, how about 'protected static'?  and can u give a simple example?

Comment: There's nothing special about *protected* static. The code example shows `protected static`. On the contrary, `public static` is just a global variable and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Non static methods cannot be called inside static methods (without instantiating the class).  protected static would make it inaccessible from outside classes, but still accessible from a public static method.  This might be to break apart a complex part of code into more maintainable blocks or if there is narrow reuse inside another static method.

Comment: can u give me one example for better understanding?